# Malformed json string perl, youtube api key

Tags: json, perl, decode

i am getting an error which i can't find the solution for .. i've spent hours on it and didn't find any fix yet. Maybe, you could help me out ? It's in perl and this is the code I am using.

```
method getMusicInformation($strMusicID) {
    my $strLink = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=YqeW9_5kURI&key=AIzaSyBpzQDzTu7e59mxD9HxYP3MTdlCUWzuirQ&part=snippet";
    my $strDetails = get($strLink);
    my $arrDetails = decode_json($strDetails);
    while (my($key, $value) = each(%{$arrDetails})) {
        if (ref($value) eq 'ARRAY') {
            while (my($second_key, $second_value) = each(@{$value})) {
                return $second_value;
            }
        }
    }
```

}

And there is the error i get in the console:

```
Error: malformed JSON string, neither array, object, number, string or atom, at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at Server/Systems/Music.pm line 38.
```

The line 38 is:

```
my $arrDetails = decode_json($strDetails);
```

Thank you for understanding.

Comment: And what is the string that you're trying to run `decode_json` on???

Comment: Which JSON module are you using? Using JSON.pm and LWP::Simple it Works For Me™

Comment: `at character offset 0 (before "(end of string)")` indicates an empty string (or undef) was passed to `decode_json`.

Comment: If that's your real API key, you should get a new one immediately.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is you're getting nothing back from `get`. The query is failing and you're not checking for an error. (Don't worry, it took me a while to figure this out, too). The clue is `at character offset 0` meaning the start of the string.

LWP::Simple is too simple and does not support error checking. Instead, use the full blown LWP::UserAgent. Fortunately [it's gotten a lot easier to use](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#REQUEST-METHODS).

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Carp;

...

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get($strLink);
if( !$response->is_success ) {
    croak "Fetching $strLink failed: ".$response->status_line;
}

my $arrDetails = decode_json($response->decoded_content);
```

In my case, the problem is this:

```
Fetching https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=YqeW9_5kURI&key=AIzaSyBpzQDzTu7e59mxD9HxYP3MTdlCUWzuirQ&part=snippet failed: 501 Protocol scheme 'https' is not supported (LWP::Protocol::https not installed) at /Users/schwern/tmp/test.pl line 15.
    main::getMusicInformation(10) called at /Users/schwern/tmp/test.pl line 30
```

So I need to install LWP::Protocol::https to have https support. You probably do, too.